# Why are objects inserted in database in the setup_all block not appearing in a test block?

Tags: elixir, ecto, ex-unit

I have similar tests in controllers and the `setup_all` inserts are available in the test blocks. Here I'm trying to allow the same thing in my models and I can't seem to make it work.

I have a test as follows:

```
defmodule Faq.QuestionTest do
  use Faq.ModelCase

  alias Faq.Question

  setup_all do
    :ok = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.checkout(Repo)

    Question.changeset(%Question{}, %{question: "Unanswered", answer: nil})                                                           |> Repo.insert!
    Question.changeset(%Question{}, %{question: "Answered",   answer: "My published answer", published_at: Ecto.DateTime.utc(:usec)}) |> Repo.insert!

    published_count = Question |> Question.published |> Repo.all |> Enum.count
    assert 1 == published_count

    IO.puts "SETUP_ALL"

    :ok
  end

  describe "scopes" do
    test "answered", meta do
      published_count = Question |> Question.published |> Repo.all |> Enum.count
      assert 1 == published_count
    end
  end
end
```

When I run it I have the following error:

```
$ mix test test/models/question_test.exs
warning: variable meta is unused
  test/models/question_test.exs:21

SETUP_ALL


  1) test scopes answered (Faq.QuestionTest)
    test/models/question_test.exs:21
    Assertion with == failed
    code: 1 == published_count
    lhs:  1
    rhs:  0
    stacktrace:
      test/models/question_test.exs:23: (test)



Finished in 0.09 seconds
1 test, 1 failure
```

Now in the `setup_all` block I make the same validation as I do in my `test` block.  Why would it fail in the test but pass in the `setup_all`?

Comment: Does `setup` instead of `setup_all` work correctly for you?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that `ModelCase` was running the first line of `setup_all` again on each run thus invalidating my connection. This line right here: `:ok = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.checkout(Repo)`